# What is the IPv6 equivalent for SIOCADDRT?

Tags: c, unix, network-programming

Can SIOCADDRT be used to add IPv6 routes? If not, what's the equivalent for ioctl()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know, but

```
# strace ip route add <ipv6-route>
```

should tell you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use SIOCADDRT. Just create AF_INET6 socket for it.  For example, take a look at Busybox implementation of "[route](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/route.c)" command. Also consider using Netlink instead, perhaps via [libnl](http://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/).

Sorry for late answer, I was looking for this myself and found the accepted answer a bit lacking.

Answer (score -1):

Not writing low-level network configuration code in your program, but instead delegating the task to the existing system utilities, would be one very good solution.

Comment: Please don't assume you know better than the questioner what the correct approach to their problem is.  It happens that from time to time people *are* wrong about that, but it's rude, and often just plain wrong, to start from that perspective.

Comment: I generally agree with that sentiment, but this is still one valid solution to the problem.